# Can't connect to BeagleBone Webserver?

Tags: beagle-bone

I'm following this [getting started](http://beagleboard.org/getting-started) tutorial, connected the board to USB and it's detected as mass storage, got the driver installed (Win 64), and at the third step I wasn't able to connect to BeagleBone webserver at 192.168.7.2, anything I did wrong? Please help.

Here is some troubleshooting info from Getting Started page, I've followed them all. I'm using Chrome, tried the node-webkit based application, not in a Virtual Machine, not using SSH just trying to access the webserver.

> **Troubleshooting**
>
> Do not use Internet Explorer.
>
> One option to browse your board is to use this node-webkit based
>   application (currently limited to Windows machines):
>   beaglebone-getting-started.zip.
>
> Virtual machines are not recommended when using the direct USB
>   connection. It is recommended you use only network connections to your
>   board if you are using a virtual machine.
>
> When using 'ssh' with the provided image, the username is 'root' and
>   the password is blank.
>
> Visit beagleboard.org/support for additional debugging tips.

UPDATE:
- I tried to install Ubuntu on my machine and connect the BeagleBone, it need not any driver and I can immediately access the webserver after ejecting the mass storage, enabling the 'USB-to-Ethernet Interface'. However in Windows ejecting the mass storage still does nothing. Still trying to make it connect in Windows.

Comment: Can you ping it?

Comment: I can't. I have made some progress by connecting via Linux instead of Windows, I'll update the post. Please take a look at the post.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about the issues you are encountering in the third step.  When you connect the board, do you see the green banner at the top of the webpage stating "Your board is connected!"?

Comment: I don't see any green bar, is it in the getting started page? Even in Linux which is my BB is accessible there is no green bar.

Comment: Yes, the green bar should be on the top of the getting started page.  You're running a 64-bit windows, right? Also what revision of the beaglebone do you have?

Comment: Yes it's Windows 8.1 64 bit, still I can't see the green bar. It's Rev A6 in the box, is it outdated?

Comment: It works out of the blue now :/

Comment: It doesn't work again I'm at loss..

Comment: The latest version of Debian image fixed my problem.